# Test for Linearity and Independence

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, linear-regression, data-analysis

When I try to run this I get the ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series

How would I go about solving this?

```
df_pred = pd.DataFrame()

df_pred["Actual Values"] = y_train  # actual values
df_pred["Fitted Values"] = olsmod2.fittedvalues  # predicted values
df_pred["Residuals"] = olsmod2.resid  # residuals

df_pred.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

If y_train, olsmod2.fittedvalues, olsmod2.resid are numpy arrays or lists with same length, then syntax for what you are trying to do is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
"Actual Values":y_train,
"Fitted Values":olsmod2.fittedvalues,
"Residuals":olsmod2.resid
})
```